# Unable to install karma in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04, karma-runner

While trying to install karma in ubuntu using command

```
sudo npm install -g karma
```

i'm getting errors like

```
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:238:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:910:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

And a number of errors like

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

And it's not getting installed.Any help would be appreciated.My `node.js version is v0.10.13`

Answer (score 5):

my npn install karma failed and
i resolved my problems with

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

on ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 running without sudo, removing the -g option solved the problem installing it locally

```
npm install karma
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, fixed by downloading the source code for 0.10.15 version. `./configure && make && sudo make install` then `sudo npm install -g karma` and it works!

Comment: worked for me. Here in more detail on how to install node without apt-get http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/05/06/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu/

Comment: great.. another option is to use PPA by chris-lea: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem installing the karma into the ubuntu inside vagrant. In my case, the install looks good, but don't work as expected.

```
$ sudo npm install --global karma
$ karma
No command 'karma' found, did you mean:
 Command 'karm' from package 'ktimetracker' (main)
karma: command not found
```

But, looking in the installation output, I could find where the karma was really installed:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma
```

If want to just type karma and run, just run:

```
 $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma /usr/bin/karma & chmod +x /usr/bin/karma
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to install nvm (in order to change node's version), and then Nicolas's instructions:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
source ~/.profile
nvm ls-remote
nvm install 0.10.15
which node
node --version
sudo npm install karma
node --version
./configure
make 
sudo make install
sudo npm install -g karma
```